# Если авторские слова — отдельное предложение

Tags: цитата

У Розенталя:

2. Если авторские слова, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они начинаются с прописной буквы:

— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.

У Гоголя:

Хозяйка уже изъявила было готовность послать за пуховиками и подушками, но хозяин сказал: «Ничего, мы отдохнем в креслах», — и хозяйка ушла.

Согласно Розенталю, надо ли было написать:

Хозяйка уже изъявила было готовность послать за пуховиками и подушками, но хозяин сказал: «Ничего, мы отдохнем в креслах». — И хозяйка ушла.

Или если авторские слова, стоящие после прямой речи, не представляют собой отдельное предложение, возможно написать:

— Скорей, загорелась школа! — и он побежал по домам будить людей.

Comment: Опечатка и недотире в вопросе!

Answer (score 2):

> Согласно Розенталю, надо ли было написать:
>
> Хозяйка уже изъявила было готовность послать за пуховиками и
>   подушками, но хозяин сказал: «Ничего, мы отдохнем в креслах». — И
>   хозяйка ушла.

Нет, не надо. Хоть теоретически возможно, если автор настаивает. 
Авторские слова после прямой речи являются здесь продолжением фразы, начатой до прямой речи. Иногда бывает сложно оценить, так ли это, тогда автор выбором пунктуации может уточнить свое понимание. Но у Гоголя тут сомнений не возникает уже хотя бы по союзу "И", Ваш вариант смотрится много хуже.

> Или если авторские слова, стоящие после прямой речи, не представляют
>   собой отдельное предложение, возможно написать:
>
> — Скорей, загорелась школа! — и он побежал по домам будить людей.

Без авторских слов, предшествующих прямой речи, и без прямой связи авторских слов с прямой речью этот вариант много хуже. Но в принципе, думаю, формальной ошибки тут нет, формулировку Розенталя следует считать рекомендательной.